# Sigmoid function prediction generates continuous number and error when exported to DF

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, sigmoid

I am new to tensorflow so I am trying to get my hands dirty by working on a binary classification problem on kaggle. I have trained the model using sigmoid function and got a very good accuracy when tested but when I try to export the prediction to df for submission, I get the error below...I have attached the code and the prediction and the output, please suggest what I am doing wrong, I suspect it has to do with my sigmoid function, thanks.

```py
This is output of the predictions....the expected is 1s and 0s

INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./movie_review_variables
Prections are [[3.8743019e-07]
 [9.9999821e-01]
 [1.7650980e-01]
 ...
 [9.9997473e-01]
 [1.4901161e-07]
 [7.0333481e-06]]
```

```py
#Importing tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
#defining hyperparameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1000
batch_size = 100
num_labels = 2
num_features = 5000
train_size = 20000

#defining the placeholders and encoding the y placeholder
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_features])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])
y_oneHot = tf.one_hot(Y, 1)

#defining the model parameters -- weight and bias
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_features, 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

#defining the sigmoid model and setting up the learning algorithm
y_model = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W), b))
cost = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_model, labels=y_oneHot)
train_optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

#defining operation to measure success rate
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_model, 1), tf.argmax(y_oneHot, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

#saving variables
saver = tf.train.Saver()

#executing the graph and saving the model variables
with tf.Session() as sess: #new session
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    #Iteratively updating parameter batch by batch
    for step in range(training_epochs * train_size // batch_size):
        offset = (step * batch_size) % train_size
        batch_xs = x_train[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        batch_labels = y_train[offset:(offset + batch_size)]
        #run optimizer on batch
        err, _ = sess.run([cost, train_optimizer], feed_dict={X:batch_xs, Y:batch_labels})
        if step % 1000 ==0:
            print(step, err) #print ongoing result
    #Print final learned parameters
    w_val = sess.run(W)
    print('w', w_val)
    b_val = sess.run(b)
    print('b', b_val)
    print('Accuracy', accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X:x_test, Y:y_test}))
    save_path = saver.save(sess, './movie_review_variables')
    print('Model saved in path {}'.format(save_path))



#creating csv file for kaggle submission
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, './movie_review_variables')
    predictions = sess.run(y_model, feed_dict={X: test_data_features})
    subm2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':test['id'],'sentiment':predictions})
    subm2.to_csv('subm2nlp.csv', index=False, quoting=3)
    print("I am done predicting")
```

```py
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./movie_review_variables
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-fd74ed82109c> in <module>()
      5 #     print('Prections are {}'.format(predictions))
      6 
----> 7     subm2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':test['id'], 'sentiment':predictions})
      8     subm2.to_csv('subm2nlp.csv', index=False, quoting=3)
      9     print("I am done predicting")

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Comment: Why do you expect the output to be binary? The output of the sigmoid function is bounded by (0,1). You are also applying the activation function twice when you calculate the loss. I also think your accuracy calculation op is not appropriate for binary classification.

Comment: It seems like your specific error is related to the dimensions of your output. You can try pred = tf.squeeze(y_model). This will remove extraneous "1" dimensions from your output tensor which may be causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you @tlitfin yes you are right, it is logistic regression and the expected output is binary (0 or 1). What should my op be? I am new to tensorflow, so I have only been getting clues from textbooks, blogs and here. I have applied  tf.squeeze(y_model) but i got this ..INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./movie_review_variables
Prections are [3.8743019e-07 9.9999821e-01 1.7650980e-01 ... 9.9997473e-01 1.4901161e-07
 7.0333481e-06] still not the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set some threshold for the sigmoidal output. E.g. split the outputs into bins with space of 0.5 between them:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
>>> x
array([ 0.        ,  0.52631579,  1.05263158,  1.57894737,  2.10526316,
        2.63157895,  3.15789474,  3.68421053,  4.21052632,  4.73684211,
        5.26315789,  5.78947368,  6.31578947,  6.84210526,  7.36842105,
        7.89473684,  8.42105263,  8.94736842,  9.47368421, 10.        ])
>>> q = 0.5     # The continuous value between two discrete points
>>> y = q * np.round(x/q)
>>> y
array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5.5,
        6. ,  6.5,  7. ,  7.5,  8. ,  8.5,  9. ,  9.5, 10. ])
```

Comment: I was able to set threshold and it worked. The predictions were extracted (prediction[:,0]) and I used numpy to round the values as you suggested. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can see the definition of the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function). This will always have a continuous output. If you want to discretize your output, you need to determine some threshold above which you will set your solution to 1 and below will be zero.

```py
pred = tf.math.greater(y_model, tf.constant(0.5))
```

However, you must be careful choosing an appropriate threshold as it is not guaranteed that your model will be well calibrated with probability. You can choose a suitable threshold based on the best discrimination on some held-out validation set.

It is important that this step is for evaluation only as you will not be able to backpropagate your loss signal through this op.

Comment: Thanks @tlitfin I have been able to make the output discrete and got a decent result upon submission. I should note tf.math.greater() returns bool, but I was able to use the idea to round the output